# How can I stop the Task.Run()?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

I'm newer to the concept of threading and I would like to use `Task` that is a component of `Thread` in my application because the save task takes time for executing.

This is my code:

```
    private void SaveItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Button Save Click ( Save to the database )

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var itemsS = Gridview.Items;

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                foreach (ItemsModel item in itemsS)
                {
                    PleaseWaittxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                    bool testAdd = new Controller().AddItem(item);
                    if (testAdd)
                        Console.WriteLine("Add true to Items ");
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Add failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                PleaseWaittxt.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            });
        });

        MessageBox.Show("Save Done"); 

        // update the gridView
        var results = new Controller().GetAllItems();
        Gridview.ItemsSource = null;
        Gridview.ItemsSource = results;
        Gridview.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

The problem is that when I save all items, I got duplicate data in the database. Otherwise, the count of `ItemsS` is fixed to 300, but after the saving, I got 600,

Did `Task.Run()` repeat the save task to the database ?

**NB:** I'm working on UI project ( WPF Desktop app )

Comment: What's the point of calling Task.Run() in that method when the internal Action will be called synchronously anyway? It would be better to remove that boilerplate and just call the Dispatcher as-is.

Comment: The task takes time to execute ( save more than 1000 rows to the database ) , for that reason I need to use multithreading.

Comment: Is the "save task" included in the question's code, or it has been omitted for brevity?

Comment: Yes the code is about an event of button click that executing the " save task " ( save to the database )

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 Well then you're wrong. It apparently works fine without. That code isn't multi-threaded, nor aynchronous.

Comment: @SimonC , but it blocks me to use anything else when saving to the database, I would like to use another task like consult another gridview during the Save task!?

Comment: @SimonC he's working with an UI thread and in order to not block the UI he's using task.run to push work to a background thread. Dispatcher.Invoke woud run the method on the main thread still so he's trying to work around this i'm guessing

Comment: @sommmen , that's absolutely right. Thank you for helping me to clarify my problem.

Comment: @sommmen Yes I got that too. But in that case, one would use a `private async void SaveItem(whatever) { await Task.Run() }` or `Task.Run(async () => {})`

Comment: @SimonC You're right - and that is actually the correct answer. Problem is he's also doing some UI stuff which would need to be moved out of the task

Comment: @SimonC, Could you please reformulate your comment in a clear answer?

Comment: Well why isn't the database call `async` also?

Comment: "The task takes time to execute ( save more than 1000 rows to the database ) , for that reason I need to use multithreading." - No, that's you thinking that it will speed it up. It won't. Threads are useful for in-memory operations, not IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you'd need something along the lines of this.
I quickly whipped it up but i hope its enough to attempt a fix yourself.

```cs
private async void SaveItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  try {
    var itemsS = GridviewServices.Items.ToList(); // to list makes shallow copy

    await Task.Run(() => {
          foreach (ItemsModel item in itemsS)
          {
              bool testAdd = new Controller().AddItem(item);
          } 
      });

    // Dont update ui in task.run, because only the ui thread may access UI items
    // Do so here - after the await. (or use dispatcher.invoke).

   GridviewServices.Items.Clear(); 
   GridviewServices.Items = itemsS;
 
  } catch { ... } // Handle exceptions, log them or something. Dont throw in async void!
 
}
```

I'm also thinking this would work:

```cs
  private async void SaveItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Button Save Click ( Save to the database )

        var itemsS = GridviewServices.Items;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
                foreach (ItemsModel item in itemsS)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {PleaseWaittxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;})

                    bool testAdd = new Controller().AddItem(item);
                    if (testAdd)
                        Console.WriteLine("Add true to Items ");
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Add failed");
                        return;
                    }
              
                }
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {PleaseWaittxt.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;})
        });

        MessageBox.Show("Save Done"); 

        // update the gridView
        var results = new Controller().GetAllItems();
        Gridview.ItemsSource = null;
        Gridview.ItemsSource = results;
        Gridview.Items.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: This answer could be an answer, but it doesn't work for me, I still got duplicated results

Comment: Perhaps - but that is a seperate issue from what you're asking here. Why not check if the entity exists in the db first in the Controller.AddItem method? Maybe add the contents from theat method to the Q so that we can take a look.

Comment: Thanks , it works now and it was a bug in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running in to, is because the Task you're executing isn't running in parallel, but synchronously to the rest of your application.

When you're running CPU-intensive tasks in the background of your UI-application, you'll want to either work with actual threads or async/await - which is what you attempted with your code.

What you'll want to do is something similar to this:

```cs
private async void SaveItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => await Task.Run(
/*optionally make this async too*/() => {
    // Execute your CPU-intensive task here
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        // Handle your UI updates here
    });
});
```

This is just a general overview, I don't know your exact use-case, but this should get you started in the right direction.

One thing to be weary of when using Lambdas and such, is closures.
If your application tends to use a lot of memory, you might want to re-think the structure of your calltree and minimize closures in your running application.

Comment: I still got duplicated results in the database!!